# When is libc++ sources needed when building Clang from sources?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm, libc++

I've been building Clang for years on Linux and OS X. From the [LLVM Download page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), I've always used the following sources:

- LLVM (LLVM source)
- Compiler Front End (Clang source)
- Compiler RT (Runtime source)
- Compiler Tools (Tools Extra sources)

The recipe I am using to download, build and install Clang 3.5 can be found at [Clang 3.5 download, build and install script](http://pastebin.com/xsy47bFR).

Its works great on OS X 10.7 and 10.8, and I've never needed the libc++ gear on OS X 10.7.x or 10.8.x (that's about 2010 or so through current).

**Question**: when does one need the libc++ and libc++ ABI sources?

---

I'm trying to help troubleshoot the inability to compile a simple C++ "Hello World" program on OS X 10.9. Clang 3.5 installed in `/usr/local` (just like the others), but its failing to find headers (like `<iostream>`) and it encounters undefined symbols during link (like `"std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))"`).

I'm wondering if 10.7 and 10.8 had headers and libraries where previous versions of Clang expected, but 10.9 needs them built and installed.

**Question**: is this symptomatic of a missing libc++ and libc++ ABI?

Comment: No, your self-compiled clang cannot find the headers since additional system included header directories (specified by `-cxx-isystem`) aren't configured correctly. You can use `clang++ -E -x c++ /dev/null -v` to find the directories clang searched and find whether they contain the headers like `iostream`. If not, you might need to export `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to include the additional directories. You can get the locations that contain the headers by use the above command for the builtin clang(`/usr/bin/clang`).

Comment: libc++ is a counterpart of libstdc++ on GNU/Linux and provide the implementation of core c++ standard library.

Comment: Thanks @Hongxu. Yes, I know what libc++ is. I'm wondering if/when its needed. I *think* its needed on Linux all the time; and its not needed on OS X. That's if I am reading ["libc++" C++ Standard Library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) correctly (which I may not be doing since I can't get `make cxx` to work either even though I'm building in-tree).

Comment: @Hongxu - *"... you might need to export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH to include the additional directories"* - so I'm clear: I would export `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to where the headers are on the 10.9 system and then kick off a Clang/LLVM build?

Comment: @Hongxu - I think I need to do more reading on this... I have too little information to be helpful, but too much information so I'm dangerous. Funny how that works...

Comment: libc++ is not required for Linux or mac os; but apple has now replaced libstdc++ with libc++ on Darwin by default; with Clang you can explicitly choose to link your C++ src against libc++ `-stdlib=libc++`. export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH so that your self-built Clang can find headers like `iostream`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question since it's like a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The keypoint is that headers and implementation has loose relationship in C/C++. I'd recommend a book [Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries](http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Started-LLVM-Core-Libraries/dp/1782166920) but that seems overkilled.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the libc++ sources checked out when building/installing clang such that you will also install the C++ STL.

If you don't have a libc++ runtime on your system, you should checkout and install libc++abi and libc++ which can be done standalone and independently of their checkout in your llvm/clang install.

As reference, I suggest you take a look at the libcxxabi, libcxx, libunwind, and llvm-X.Y ports in MacPorts which show how I've configured these projects to build on Leopard through Yosemite.