# Unknown package libcxx and libcxxabi when building Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libc++

I'm trying to build Clang with libc++ from sources. And I'm trying to drop libc++ in-tree while building it out-of-tree with the other components. The recipe I use is below.

If I simply place `libcxx` and `libcxxabi` in-tree, then configure ***does not*** pick them up, and they are not built automatically. I placed them in `llvm/projects` per [LLVM's libc++ Standard Library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

Additionally, adding `make cxx` to the recipe does not work as advertised on the [LLVM's libc++ Standard Library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) page. It results in:

```
llvm[0]: Constructing LLVMBuild project information.
make: *** No rule to make target `cxx'.  Stop.
```

When I configure LLVM/Clang with `--with-libcxx` and `--with-libcxxabi`:

```bash
# Issued from a scratch 'build' directory, which is next to the 'llvm' directory.
../llvm/configure --enable-optimized --enable-cxx11 --with-libcxx --with-libcxxabi \
    $OTHER_OPTIONS --prefix=/usr/local
```

then I receive the following:

```
configure: WARNING: Unknown project (libcxx) won't be configured automatically
configure: WARNING: Unknown project (libcxxabi) won't be configured automatically
```

`libcxx` and `libcxxabi` are literally what LLVM calls them, so I'm not sure what names to use if they are not correct.

I tried to examine `configure` for what the package names should be, but its not very helpful. See below for the logic.

How do I configure and build Clang with libc++ (when libc++ and libc++ ABI are in-tree)?

---

Configure logic for `--with-XXX` is shown below.

this is all I can find (its not very helpful):

```
  -with-* | --with-*)
    ac_package=`expr "x$ac_option" : 'x-*with-\([^=]*\)'`
    # Reject names that are not valid shell variable names.
    expr "x$ac_package" : ".*[^-_$as_cr_alnum]" >/dev/null &&
      { echo "$as_me: error: invalid package name: $ac_package" >&2
   { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
    ac_package=`echo $ac_package| sed 's/-/_/g'`
    eval with_$ac_package=\$ac_optarg ;;
```

---

Related links:

- [LLVM/Clang download page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html)
- [LLVM's libc++ Standard Library page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)

And this Stack Overflow question is related: [When is libc++ sources needed when building Clang from sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27812611)

And this discussion of CFE-Dev mailing list: [Questions about libc++ for linux and its git repository (if any)](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-July/thread.html). The thread says unpacking libcxx into `llcm/projects` ensures the headers are copied where Clang expects them during `make install`. But it does not address the `--with-XXX` question, it does not discuss why `libc++` was not built, and it does not discuss how to get `make install` to actually install the libraries.

---

Recipe to fetch and build Clang. It works fine when ***not*** including `libcxx` and `libcxxabi`.

```bash
#! /bin/sh

# Clang 3.5 recipe.
#   The script should be run from a scratch directory.

# Fetch

if [ ! -e llvm-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/llvm-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

if [ ! -e cfe-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/cfe-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

if [ ! -e compiler-rt-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/compiler-rt-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

if [ ! -e libcxx-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/libcxx-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

if [ ! -e libcxxabi-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/libcxxabi-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

if [ ! -e clang-tools-extra-3.5.0.src.tar.xz ]; then
  wget http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/clang-tools-extra-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
fi

# Cleanup

echo "Cleaning up artifacts"
rm -rf llvm build llvm-3.5.0.src

# LLVM
echo "Unpacking LLVM"
tar xf llvm-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv llvm-3.5.0.src/ llvm

# Clang Front End
echo "Unpacking Clang Front End"
cd llvm/tools
tar xf ../../cfe-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv cfe-3.5.0.src clang
cd ../../

# Compiler RT
echo "Unpacking Compiler RT"
cd llvm/projects
tar xf ../../compiler-rt-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv compiler-rt-3.5.0.src/ compiler-rt
cd ../../

# Extra Tools
echo "Unpacking Extra Tools"
cd llvm/tools/clang/tools/
tar xf ../../../../clang-tools-extra-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv clang-tools-extra-3.5.0.src extra
cd ../../../../

# libc++
echo "Unpacking libc++"
cd llvm/projects
tar xf ../../libcxx-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv libcxx-3.5.0.src/ libcxx
cd ../../

# libc++ ABI
echo "Unpacking libc++ ABI"
cd llvm/projects
tar xf ../../libcxxabi-3.5.0.src.tar.xz
mv libcxxabi-3.5.0.src/ libcxxabi
cd ../../

# Determine if Apple
IS_DARWIN=`uname -s | egrep -i -c "Darwin"`
if [ $IS_DARWIN -ne 0 ]; then
  OTHER_OPTIONS=" --enable-libcpp"
fi

# Configure
echo "Configuring build"
mkdir -p build
cd build
../llvm/configure --enable-optimized --enable-cxx11 --with-libcxx --with-libcxxabi $OTHER_OPTIONS --prefix=/usr/local

# Build
# 'make cxx' for libc++ is from http://libcxx.llvm.org/
echo "Running make"
make cxx
make -j2

RET=$?
if [ $RET -eq 0 ];then
    echo "****************************************"
    read -p "Press [ENTER] to install, or [CTRL]+C to quit"
    sudo make install
fi

# ****************************************
# ****************************************

# Install does not install scan-build and scan-view
# Perform the copy, and/or put them on-path

#sudo cp llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py /usr/local/bin
#sudo 2to3 -w /usr/local/bin/asan_symbolize.py

#sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/scan-build
#sudo cp -r llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build /usr/local/bin

#sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/scan-view
#sudo cp -r llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Those install instructions assume that you checked them out with svn (that's what I did.) I'm assuming that using the tar balls would contain different install instructions (try looking for README or INSTALL, I've never tried it.) I also used `cmake` per the instructions before running `make`.

Comment: @remyabel - I don't use bleeding edge from SVN. I use stable as published on the download page. Is there a way to know what revision was 3.5.0? (I don't use CMAKE either, but that's another problem I'll tackle when I cross that bridge).

Comment: @remyabel - this is related (from 10,000 feet). I *thought* the various LLVM packages were cohesive, and one should be able to mix/match them *à la carte* (within reason). The more I try and do basic things like configure, build and install, I am finding its not the case. Am I doing something wrong, or are these packages fractured so they don't fit well together during configure, build and install.

Comment: @remyabel - to address you question on `README`, it useless. There's no `INSTALL`. There's a `LLVMBuild.txt` and it points me to `http://llvm.org/docs/LLVMBuild.html`. And `http://llvm.org/docs/LLVMBuild.html` does not have instructions on adding components *à la carte*. I *think* the LLVM project thinks this stuff just works out of the box (when in practice, it does not). Or I'm operating the build system out of its specification.

Comment: @remyabel - thanks for the help. I'm going to move this to CFE-Dev. I'm encountering too many problems, and I need the project to discuss some of them since folks like you and I have different expectations (like we expect it to work out of the box).

Comment: I don't know whether it's because that you compile llvm with autotools(https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/projects/Makefile). Have you tried compiled with CMake?

Answer (score 3):

This is script which I used to build libcxxabi and libcxx. It use previously built Clang (with GCC (4.8.3 in my case) and GCC STL):

```
if ( $#argv != 2 ) then
    echo "Usage: [32|64] <directory>"
    exit
endif

set echo on

set CMake=<CMake executable>
set GCCDir=<recent GCC directory>
set LLVMSourceDir=${PWD}/llvm-${LLVM_VERSION}.src
set LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir=${PWD}
set LLVMPass1Dir=${PWD}/pass1
set PythonDir=<Python directory>
set InstallDir=${PWD}/$argv[2]

if ( $argv[1] == 32 ) then
    set GCC_EHDir=${GCCDir}/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/32
    set BuildMode="-m32"
    set LibDirSuffix=""
else
    set GCC_EHDir=${GCCDir}/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3
    set BuildMode="-m64"
    set LibDirSuffix="64"
endif

set BuildDir=libcxxabi.build

if ( -d ${BuildDir} ) then
    rm -rf ${BuildDir}
endif

mkdir ${BuildDir}
cd ${BuildDir}

${CMake}                                                \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"                                    \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${InstallDir}                           \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${LLVMPass1Dir}/bin/clang                            \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${BuildMode}                                    \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${LLVMPass1Dir}/bin/clang++                        \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${BuildMode}                                  \
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-L ${GCC_EHDir}"                           \
    -DCMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS="${GCC_EHDir}/libgcc_eh.a"                      \
    -DLLVM_FORCE_USE_OLD_TOOLCHAIN=YES                              \
    -DLLVM_PATH=${LLVMSourceDir}                                    \
    -DLIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_INCLUDES=${LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir}/libcxx-${LLVM_VERSION}.src/include    \
    -DLIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_PATH=${LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir}/libcxx-${LLVM_VERSION}.src            \
    -DLIBCXXABI_LIBDIR_SUFFIX=${LibDirSuffix}                           \
    ${LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir}/libcxxabi-${LLVM_VERSION}.src

make
make install

cd ..

set BuildDir=libcxx.build

if ( -d ${BuildDir} ) then
    rm -rf ${BuildDir}
endif

mkdir ${BuildDir}
cd ${BuildDir}

${CMake}                                                \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"                                    \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${InstallDir}                           \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${LLVMPass1Dir}/bin/clang                            \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${BuildMode}                                    \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${LLVMPass1Dir}/bin/clang++                        \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${BuildMode}                                  \
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-L ${GCCDir}/lib${LibDirSuffix}"                   \
    -DLLVM_PATH=${LLVMSourceDir}                                    \
    -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI=libcxxabi                                  \
    -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_INCLUDE_PATHS=${LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir}/libcxxabi-${LLVM_VERSION}.src/include  \
    -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI_LIBRARY_PATH=${InstallDir}/lib                         \
    -DLIBCXX_LIBDIR_SUFFIX=${LibDirSuffix}                              \
    -DLIT_EXECUTABLE=${LLVMSourceDir}/utils/lit/lit.py                      \
    ${LLVMOutOfTreeSourceDir}/libcxx-${LLVM_VERSION}.src

make
make install

cd ..
```

Answer (score 2):

libc++ and libc++abi aren't maintained to work with configure. I think libc++ might work if you invoke it correctly, but there isn't even a configure script for libc++abi.

See [our docs](http://libcxx.llvm.org) for using cmake with these projects:

```
# In-tree build:
# Check out libcxx and libcxxabi into llvm/projects
cd llvm
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. # Linux may require -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
make cxx
```

Comment: This is what the question says doesn't work – `make: *** No rule to make target cxx'.  Stop.`

Comment: Yes, and the question also invoked configure, not cmake.

Comment: I would add then that cmake must run after the `libcxx` and `libcxxabi` projects have been checked out – or alternatively, after deleting the cmake cache. Else `make` will error out saying it failed to find the targets.