# Missing libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a file for LLVM compiler-rt

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I've just built LLVM/Clang [compiler-rt](http://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) and tried the `-fsanitize` option. But strangely the link failed since it cannot find `libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a`.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /home/hongxu/RESEARCH/llvm-git/obj/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
clang-3.7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I changed into directory `/home/hongxu/RESEARCH/llvm-git/obj/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.0/lib/linux/`, I found that there are other library files

```
# AddressSanitizer
libclang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.asan-preinit-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a
# DataFlowSanitizer
libclang_rt.dfsan-libc-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.dfsan-x86_64.a
# LeakSanitizer
libclang_rt.lsan-x86_64.a
# MemorySanitizer
libclang_rt.msan-x86_64.a
# ThreadSanitizer
libclang_rt.tsan-x86_64.a
# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer
libclang_rt.ubsan_cxx-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone_cxx-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64.a
libclang_rt.ubsan-x86_64.a
```

And I can guess their functionalities from the name according to compiler-rt page.

But what is `libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a`? And how can I get it?

Comment: OK, I just downloaded and build Clang 3.6. I can confirm `libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a` is *not* part of Clang 3.6. It probably means its not part of 3.7 either. It was present in Clang 3.5 and earlier. But I'm not having trouble with a missing `libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a` with Clang 3.6 on OS X.

Comment: (Continued) I'm having trouble with other missing symbols (see [Clang 3.6 and undefined symbol "ubsan::checkDynamicType"](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-users/2015-April/000668.html)), and I think they are related to `libcxx` and `libcxxabi`. From [Unknown package libcxx and libcxxabi when building Clang?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27881949), I know `libcxx` and `libcxxabi` don't work with Autotools/Makefiles, so I don't even bother to download them. Maybe I need to switch to Cmake, download and build them...

Comment: @jww I haven't encountered this issue and I don't have any libcxx/libcxxabi installed before. I'm using CMake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for @jww's answer; but *my* problem is different.

I've got replies from llvmdev mailing list (see [the thread](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2015-April/084146.html)) and they said that:

> libclang_rt.san is now gone. Fresh compiler-rt build doesn't contain this library, and fresh Clang is not using it.

And I failed to compile since I didn't sync the other llvm projects before compiling (I only put compiler-rt inside llvm/projects directory and build from llvm build root directory).

And the solution is simple:

> Trying building from scratch (remove the build directory, sync all llvm subprojects to the same revision, build again).

Comment: I've built everything from release 3.7.0, even so I'm seeing the same error.

Comment: @user better ask on mailing list; or use an old version.

Answer (score 8):

> But strangely the link failed since it cannot find libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a.

Yeah, `make install` does not install some things that are needed. Other times, it installs them in non-standard locations.

Other things it does not install includes `asan_symbolize.py`, which is used to symbolicate dumps from Address Sanitizer (ASan).

---

> But what is libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a? And how can I get it?

Its one of the sanitizer libraries. You probably have it, you just don't realize it because its in a non-standard location. For example, on my system (where I build LLVM/Clang myself):

```sh
$ find /usr -name libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a 2>/dev/null 
/usr/local/lib/clang/3.5.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.san-x86_64.a
```

So what you have to do is use either `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (Linux) or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (OS X) to ensure the compiler driver can find it. You should ***never*** have to manually add the various sanitizer libraries - the compiler driver should always add them for you.

For completeness, Clang 3.4 installed the sanitizers libraries at `/usr/local/lib/clang/3.4/lib/linux/` on Linux; and Clang 3.3 installed them at `/usr/local/lib/clang/3.3/lib/darwin/` on OS X.

You can actually change search directories in the source code and they will be picked up automatically by the compiler driver. I think I had to change the actual sources because I could not find a configure option to add locations like `/usr/local/lib/clang/<version>/lib/linux/`. Take a look at `tools/clang/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp` and friends. That's where paths like `.../include/c++/4.2.1` come from.

---

By the way, here's how to use Address Sanitizer and `asan_symbolize.py`. First, run `2to3` and `asan_symbolize.py` to fix what the Python folks broke related to basic I/O:

```sh
$ find Clang-3.5/ -name asan_symbolize.py
Clang-3.5/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py
2to3 -w Clang-3.5/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py

echo "" | Clang-3.5/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py
# Fix errors 2to3 missed
```

Then, copy it to a well known location (or put it on path):

```sh
sudo cp Clang-3.5/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py /usr/local/bin
```

Then, for your project:

```sh
export CPPFLAGS="-fsanitze=undefined -fsanitize=address"
export CFLAGS="-fsanitze=undefined -fsanitize=address"
export CXXFLAGS="-fsanitze=undefined -fsanitize=address -fno-sanitize=vptr"
export CC=/usr/local/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/clang++
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/clang/3.5.0/lib/linux

./configure
make
make check 2>&1 | asan_symbolize.py
```

`CPPFLAGS` is actually quite important for an Autotools project. Otherwise, you get the dreaded *C compiler cannot create executables* error.

When you have a ASan error, you will see similar to:

```sh
make test 2>&1 | asan_symbolize.py
...

/usr/local/bin/clang -fsanitize=address -Xlinker -export-dynamic
    -o python Modules/python.o libpython3.3m.a -ldl -lutil
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a -lm
./python -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
=================================================================
==24064==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address
0x619000004020 at pc 0x4ed4b2 bp 0x7fff80fff010 sp 0x7fff80fff008
READ of size 4 at 0x619000004020 thread T0
  #0 0x4ed4b1 in PyObject_Free Python-3.3.5/./Objects/obmalloc.c:987
  #1 0x7a2141 in code_dealloc Python-3.3.5/./Objects/codeobject.c:359
  #2 0x620c00 in PyImport_ImportFrozenModuleObject
       Python-3.3.5/./Python/import.c:1098
  #3 0x620d5c in PyImport_ImportFrozenModule
       Python-3.3.5/./Python/import.c:1114
  #4 0x63fd07 in import_init Python-3.3.5/./Python/pythonrun.c:206
  #5 0x63f636 in _Py_InitializeEx_Private
       Python-3.3.5/./Python/pythonrun.c:369
  #6 0x681d77 in Py_Main Python-3.3.5/./Modules/main.c:648
  #7 0x4e6894 in main Python-3.3.5/././Modules/python.c:62
  #8 0x2abf9a525eac in __libc_start_main
       /home/aurel32/eglibc/eglibc-2.13/csu/libc-start.c:244
  #9 0x4e664c in _start (Python-3.3.5/./python+0x4e664c)

AddressSanitizer can not describe address in more detail (wild
memory access suspected).
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow
  Python-3.3.5/./Objects/obmalloc.c:987 PyObject_Free
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c327fff87b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff87c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff87d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff87e0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff87f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c327fff8800: fa fa fa fa[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff8810: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff8820: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff8830: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff8840: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c327fff8850: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap right redzone:    fb
  Freed heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==24064==ABORTING
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1
```

---

There's a more complete writeup of the LLVM/Clang build process and using the santizers at Python's [Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://docs.python.org/devguide/clang.html). I wrote it a while ago, so the version and recipe are stale. But the concepts are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't found that library. Anyway, thanks SO MUCH for your tutorial, especially the asan_symbolize.py part.

Comment: Fortunately, clang 7.0 has already fix this. When compilation done, you'll find libasan libraries in `/path/to/clang-7.0/lib/clang/7.0.0/lib/linux/`

Answer (score 4):

The library is still used with clang 3.7 (when sanitizers are enabled) but if compiled using autotools, it will be missing. I found this thread by looking for a simple solution, but there doesnt seem to be any, except building all yourself with cmake.

Also see [LLVM Issue 22757 - libclang_rt.asan missing in clang-3.8 deb packages](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22757).

The other option, which I am using, is to use clang 3.6.

Comment: On Debian, see [Issue 779785: clang-3.7: -fsanitize doesn't work due to missing ubsan libraries in 3.7](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=779785).

Answer (score 0):

If you installed clang from your Linux distribution, then use the package manager to search missing package. In case of Fedora and dnf, the command is `dnf whatprovides`:

```
$ sudo dnf whatprovides '*/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so'
compiler-rt-15.0.7-1.fc37.x86_64 : LLVM "compiler-rt" runtime libraries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so
Filename    : /usr/lib64/clang/15.0.7/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so

swift-lang-5.7-1.fc37.x86_64 : The Swift programming language
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/libexec/swift/5.7/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so
```

Therefore, `sudo dnf install -y compiler-rt` will install for you this file.